# JQuery / CSS trigger animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing one pagesite.
I'm trying to make this parallelogram to disappear when i click the button for the next part.
It is working right now with the asnwers down but now i want to change the direction from right-> left to left -> right
Also i have the same animation wi height, so it hides the box

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.article").click(fucntion() {
    var para = $("#parallelogram");
    para.animate({
      width: '0px'
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#parallelogram {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  left: 430px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 1s;
}
#parallelogram:active {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="article" href="#article">Article</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class="page" id="content">
  <div id="parallelogram">

  </div>
</div>
```

How to make it from left to the right ?

P.S. Brand new in JQuery

Comment: You have a typo. `fucntion` should be `function`.

Comment: Rory McCrossan is right: http://output.jsbin.com/yaqufihufu

Comment: Yes Rory is right. Test:  https://jsfiddle.net/896xvpe4/ .

Comment: thank you for the quick answer

Answer (score 0):

Here to fix your js

**JS**

```
$(function(){
 $('.article').click(function(){
   var para = $("#parallelogram");
   para.animate({
        width: '0px'
    }, "slow");
 })
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fb5c8zmz/)

Answer (score 0):

hey try this with less code  according to your code

```
$(function(){
$('.article').click(function(){  
$("#parallelogram").animate({
    width: '0px'
}, "slow");
 })
 }
```

hello for move right --left see the below fiddle and customize it

[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/APA2S/6132/)

Comment: How can i make it to go opposite 
from right-> left to left -> right

Comment: the width should be 0.  I want to hide it completely.
With width: 0 it is just moving it a little bit in right but still is start animation from right to the left

Comment: see the updated fiddle u are looking something like this??

Comment: check the fiddle again .let me know will it be okay...or not ??